# Why are attempts to view revisions with the Google Drive API returning a 500?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-explorer

I've been working with the Google Drive API for a bit, accessing the list of revisions for two sheets as part of a job with service.revisions().list(fileId=FILE_ID).execute(). Everything was fine until earlier this morning, when one of the requests (but not the other) started returning a 500 error. This isn't intermittent - it's returning this error on every request so an exponential backoff just hits the cap I've set (5).

There's nothing of value in the response but here it is:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "internalError",
    "message": "Internal Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Internal Error"
 }
}
```

I get the same error when querying with the API explorer, so this seems to be an issue with the sheet itself as opposed to a coding problem. Here's the request URL:

https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1KYDm4gqaCLipQTskbqQbesq8ON7CmV_4IscF8V0FZrs/revisions?key=YOUR_API_KEY

What could suddenly cause this change in behavior?

Comment: Sounds like a bug you should file a bug report

Comment: Yeah, logged in Google Issue Tracker, looks like they may have broken something this morning.

Comment: Are you still experiencing this? I went and tried [revision.list try-it](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/revisions/list) and it works. Here's my [try-it screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/jNm83).

Comment: Yes I’m still experiencing the issue. It only happens with this specific file though - like I said, requesting revisions for the other file isn’t a problem.

Comment: So weird - it looks like someone touched the sheet yesterday, and now the requests are working again. The revision history is wiped out though, there's only the one from yesterday. I'd really love to know what happened.